Is my Lemon Tree Dead as a Dodo?
Hi
I bought this Meyer Lemon tree a year
Or so ago from a nursery, I was told to leave it in the pot or put it into a bigger pot
It had leaves and a few fruit but just kept careful care of it during the summer
Once winter set in I basically forgot about it, a few months ago my Mum tried to revive it by planting it in one of the soil beds we have around the garden but 2-3 months in it’s not looking any better and wondering am I flogging a dead horse?
Is there any chance of reviving it?

My Meyer's Lemon seemingly died (looking worse than yours) but came back after several months, starting new growth from lower down (as if from rootstock, except it's on its own roots, no rootstock). Everything above where the new growth emerged was dead, so I cut it off, and am letting it grow anew. If you think it is entirely dead, I'd leave it be for another 90 days just to be sure.

Are you in the UK somewhere?

I am in the UK, London to be precise

The only way you'll ever know is by scratching the bark. If it's green, congrats it's alive. Else, yes it's dead as a dodo (by the look of it, it probably is).


Except I would recommend a vertical knife cut of say 1cm. That way you can still see what's underneath but without permanently damaging the phloem. Not much at least.
